# C++ - iterator for a vector of iterators not compiling

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, stdvector

I have a templated class P that has a const_iterator and i'm trying to make a vector of said iterators and iterate through that vector:

```
std::vector<typename P<A, B>::const_iterator>::const_iterator it;
```

problem is when i try to compile i get

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
```

any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you paste the typedef of `const_iterator` in P?

Comment: I cannot =( but i guarantee it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `typename` before `std::vector<>` as well because at least one of the template parameters in `P<A, B>` is a dependent type:

```c++
typename std::vector<typename P<A, B>::const_iterator>::const_iterator it;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both uses of `const_iterator` depend on template parameters; so both need `typename`.

```
typename std::vector<typename P<A, B>::const_iterator>::const_iterator it;
^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^
```